# Python sort list of dates in [MMM dd, MMM dd...] format

Tags: python, sorting, date, operator-keyword

I have a list in the format

```
['Jan 01', 'Feb 02', 'Mar 05', 'Feb 04', 'Jan 05', ...]
```

I want to sort it to get

```
['Jan 01', 'Jan 05', 'Feb 02', 'Feb 04', 'Mar 05'...]
```

I'm aware of things like `operator.itemgetter('date')`, but don't think that will work for this format

Comment: Is your list full of strings, i.e. `['Jan 01', 'Feb 02', 'Mar 05', 'Feb 04', 'Jan 05'...]`?

Comment: `your_list.sort()` doesnt work?

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko try it - it would give `['Feb 02', 'Feb 04', 'Jan 01', 'Jan 05', 'Mar 05', ...]`, sorting lexicographically by default

Comment: no that was just an example, the list is very large. I assumed that by itself it would lexicographically sort so for instance Apr would come before Mar, but the solution below might work

Comment: oh of course, silly me .)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could parse the dates into `datetime` objects:

```
from datetime import datetime

sorted(lst, key=lambda d: datetime.strptime(d, '%b %d'))
```

The parsed `datetime` objects are then used to determine the ordering.

Demo:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> lst = ['Jan 01', 'Feb 02', 'Mar 05', 'Feb 04', 'Jan 05']
>>> sorted(lst, key=lambda d: datetime.strptime(d, '%b %d'))
['Jan 01', 'Jan 05', 'Feb 02', 'Feb 04', 'Mar 05']
```

Comment: i think this works, thank you! I wasn't sure how to formatting worked but '%b %d' seems to work

Comment: @user3752900 you can see the list of formatting directives [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)